# Laravel 5.3 - Attach Multiple Files To Mailables

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3, laravel-mail

How does one go about attaching multiple files to laravel 5.3 mailable?

I can attach a single file easily enough using `->attach($form->filePath)` on my mailable build method. However, soon as I change the form field to array I get the following error:

```
basename() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given
```

I've searched the docs and also various search terms here on stack to no avail. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Build Method:

```
public function build()
{
    return $this->subject('Employment Application')
                ->attach($this->employment['portfolio_samples'])
                ->view('emails.employment_mailview');
}
```

Mail Call From Controller:

```
Mail::to(config('mail.from.address'))->send(new Employment($employment));
```

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You should store your generated email as a variable, then you can just add multiple attachments like this:

```
public function build()
{
    $email = $this->view('emails.employment_mailview')->subject('Employment Application');
    
    // $attachments is an array with file paths of attachments
    foreach ($attachments as $filePath) {
        $email->attach($filePath);
    }

    return $email;
}
```

In this case your `$attachments` variable should be an array with paths to files:

```
$attachments = [
    // first attachment
    '/path/to/file1',

    // second attachment
    '/path/to/file2',
    ...
];
```

---

Also you can attach files not only by file paths, but with MIME type and desired filename, see documentation about second case of use for the `attachment` method: https://laravel.com/docs/master/mail#attachments

For example, your `$attachments` array can be something like this:

```
$attachments = [
    // first attachment
    'path/to/file1' => [
        'as' => 'file1.pdf',
        'mime' => 'application/pdf',
    ],
    
    // second attachment
    'path/to/file12' => [
        'as' => 'file2.pdf',
        'mime' => 'application/pdf',
    ],
    
    ...
];
```

After you can attach files from this array:

```
// $attachments is an array with file paths of attachments
foreach ($attachments as $filePath => $fileParameters) {
    $email->attach($filePath, $fileParameters);
}
```

Comment: This solution works perfectly in L5.8, but make sure to use a different name instead of `$attachments` as the internal Mailable class already has a property with the name `$attachments`. Using the same name overwrites the property and causes errors.

Comment: @Sven, thanks for your comment. However, you're wrong about the name of this example variable. Even if some class has an `$attachments` property, we still can create a variable with the same name `$attachments` because non-static properties can via the pseudo-variable `$this`, so our variable doesn't interfere with the properties of this hypothetical class. Static properties of any class can be accessed using `static` keyword, so again — our variable doesn't cause any troubles there.

Comment: @AlexanderReznikov I'm not sure what's the issue then but there might be side effects: https://stackoverflow.com/q/54262711/1815847
([source](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.8/src/Illuminate/Mail/Mailable.php#L112))

Comment: In case you mentioned user @Matt E. tries to create an own class property `$attachments` and it overwrites a Laravel `$attachment` class property.

You can you variables with the "same" names without any worries, see an example: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/8b94a2998532abf5535b724b38a6d794441db61c

Comment: @AlexanderReznikov You're right. It's only an issue with `$this->attachments`. Thank you for your patience.

Comment: Sure, no problem.

Comment: There's no need to store it in the `email` variable since you're working with an object. In the end you can just return `$this`.

Answer (score 0):

Best solution work for me

```
$email = $this->from($from)->subject("Employment Application")
    ->view('emails.employment_mailview');

foreach ($files as $file) {
    $path = '/path/to/'.$file->file;
    $attachments->push($path);
}

$attachments = collect([]);

foreach ($attachments as $filePath) {
    $email->attach($filePath);
}

return $email;
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, maybe it will work for more people.
As I am getting the files via $request this was the solution works for me.

obs: sorry I'm using translate. From Portuguese(Brazil) to English.

thanks @AlexanderReznikov, it helped me a lot.

```
class SendMailextends Mailable
   {

      protected $inputs;
      protected $files;

    public function __construct(array $inputs, array $files)
    {
            $this->inputs = $inputs;
            $this->files = $files;

    }

public function build()
{

if (isset($this->files)){
 $email =  $this->from('you@mail')->view('email.email-contact')->subject('Email teste mulptiple files');

        for ($indice = 0; $indice < count($this->files['files']); $indice++) {

                $files = $this->files[$indice];

                $pathName = $files->getPathname();

                $attachments = $pathName;

                $fileName = $files->getClientOriginalName();

                $email->attach($attachments,['as' => "$fileName"]);

            }

        return $email;

    }else{
        // file empty, send email
        return $this->from('you@mail','name')->subject('Email teste mulptiple files')
            ->view('email.email-contact');
    }
}
}
```