# Laravel: Illegal string offset 'file' on line 342, file Illuminate/Mail/Mailable.php

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to attach some documents to an email, using Laravel's `attachFromStorageDisk` method, that I read about in the documentation: [Mail - Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/mail#attachments).

```
public function build()
{
    $email = $this->view('emails.message')
        ->subject($this->emailSubject);

    foreach ($this->attachments as $attachment) {
        $email->attachFromStorageDisk('filemanager', $attachment);
    }

    return $email;
}
```

And the error I'm getting is this `Illegal string offset 'file' on line 342, file Illuminate/Mail/Mailable.php` and I can't figure out a way to fix this.

`$this->attachments` is an array containing the paths to the files I want to attach to the e-mail, and all the paths are correct.

Do you guys have any idea how to solve this? I couldn't find much about this specific error on line 342, Mailable.php

Thanks!

Comment: Try to change your `$this->attachments` to something else, looks like it's conflicting with `Mailable`

Comment: You were right! That solved it! I don't know how I didn't see that coming! Cheers man!

Comment: Glad I could help. I'll post this as an answer, so it's easer to find the information.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Change the name of your variable `$this->attachments` to something else

Mailable class already has property `$attachments`, which you are overwriting.

Comment: Laravel should have mentioned this at the start of the Attachment topic in their Mail docs page