# Email multiple images with dropzone laravel

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel, dropzone.js

I want to upload multiple image files and send it via email to customers. But the ajax request get this error `call to a member function getclientoriginalname() on array` when `uploadMultiple: true,` added to dropzone. Multiple images uploaded without that option. Anyway i want to email that multiple files, how can i do this?

dropzone js code:

```html
Dropzone.options.uploadimg = {
            paramName: "file", // The name that will be used to transfer the file
            maxFilesize: 5, //MB
            acceptedFiles: ".jpeg,.jpg,.png",
            uploadMultiple: true,
            addRemoveLinks: true,
            success: function(file, response) 
            {
                $.notify({
                    message: 'Image uploaded Successfully!' 
                    },
                    {
                    type: 'success'
                });
            },
            error: function(file, response)
            {
               return false;
               console.log('fail to upload');
            },
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            }
        }
```

SendMailController to send uploaded images.

```html
    public function sendNotifications(Request $request)
    {
        $id_int = Cookie::get('jobid');
        $img_name = Cookie::get('imgName');
        
        $data = DB::table('customers')
        ->join('jobs', 'jobs.id', '=', 'customers.id')
        ->select('firstname','email')
        ->where('jobs.id', '=', $id_int)
        ->get()->toArray();

        foreach ($data as $value) {
            $customer_firstname = $value->firstname;
            $customer_email = $value->email;
        }

        $pathToFile = public_path() . "\\uploads\\" . $img_name;

        //send the email to the relevant customer email
        Mail::to($customer_email)->send(new SendMail($customer_firstname, $pathToFile), function($message){
                $message->attach($pathToFile);
        });

    }
```

Image upload controller:

```html
class ImageUploadController extends Controller
{
    public function uploadImage(Request $request){

        $img_file = $request->file('file');
        
        $imgName = $img_file->getClientOriginalName();
        
        Cookie::queue(cookie('imgName', $imgName, $minute = 5));

        $img_file->move(public_path('uploads'), $imgName);
    }
}
```

When i uploaded multiple images and sendinding via email, it only send the last uploaded file in dropzone. How can i send all uploaded files?

Comment: The error message is pretty clear. Just do `var_dump($img_file)` and check what it actually contains? (hint, if you allow multiple uploads, they will be sent as an array of files)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since its multiple files you need to  loop through the file variable to get the files

```
class ImageUploadController extends Controller
{
    public function uploadImage(Request $request){

        $img_files = $request->file('file');
        foreach($img_files as $img_file){
            $imgName = $img_file->getClientOriginalName();

            Cookie::queue(cookie('imgName', $imgName, $minute = 5));

            $img_file->move(public_path('uploads'), $imgName);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: it only gets the first uploaded image, what is the problem?

Comment: the foreach is working, I think youre issue is with cookie logic which I dont know the reason behind it which seems to overwrite images by replacing them with same name

Comment: ahh.. thanks it works. when i tried with a expired cookie.  now the images are uploaded with a one request like 'Screenshot (384).pngScreenshot (390).png' how can i get each for sending in email controller? But that output gives with the print_r() . dd() is only shows one image name, why that happen?

Comment: you should use something like the URL : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42848363/laravel-5-3-attach-multiple-files-to-mailables