# Laravel sending attachment from two different inputs

Tags: laravel, email-attachments

I'm trying to send an email through Laravel from a form that has two different file inputs with different names, cv and cover_letter.

The build function works just fine but it only attaches one file when it sends the email, I'd like it to send both.

I've tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42848363/laravel-5-3-attach-multiple-files-to-mailables) here on SO but no luck sending both attachments either.

```
    public function build(Request $request)
    {
       $today = Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d');

        return $this->from([
            'email' => $request->email, 
            'name' => $request->name 
        ])
        ->to( 'jobs@domain.com' )
        ->subject( New job application '.$request->name.' for the position of '.$request->role.'.')
        ->view('emails.jobsform')
        ->with([    
            'name' => $request->name,
            'tel' => $request->tel,
            'email' => $request->email,
            'role' => $request->role,
            'location' => $request->location,
            'call_code' => $request->call_code,

        ])
        ->attach(
            $request->cv, [
            'as' => $today.".".$request->name.".".$request->role.'.pdf', 
            'mime' => 'application/pdf'],
            $request->cover_letter, [
                'as' => $today.".".$request->name.".".$request->role.'-Cover Letter.pdf', 
                'mime' => 'application/pdf']
            );

    }
```

Hope someone can help, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In example, he use attach with `foreach()`, it means that for new file he has new attach, and u want to attach all files in one `attach()`. Try this

```
->attach(
            $request->cv, [
            'as' => $today.".".$request->name.".".$request->role.'.pdf', 
            'mime' => 'application/pdf'])
->attach(
            $request->cover_letter, [
                'as' => $today.".".$request->name.".".$request->role.'-Cover Letter.pdf', 
                'mime' => 'application/pdf']
            );
```

Comment: Hello Bohdan, this didn't work, thanks for your input though

Comment: Hi MegaBeetle, first argument in `attach()` must be a file path, not file name, are u sure that `$request->cover_letter` and `$request->cv` has file path?

Comment: Hi, Bohdan, yeah, they do, if i send just one ```->attach(
            $request->cover_letter, [
                'as' => $today.".".$request->name.".".$request->role.'-Cover Letter.pdf', 
                'mime' => 'application/pdf']
            );```it works just fine, problem is that together both attachments don't send

Comment: try to make working attachment twice `->attach( $request->cover_letter, [ 'as' => $today.".".$request->name.".".$request->role.'-Cover Letter.pdf', 'mime' => 'application/pdf'] )->attach( $request->cover_letter, [ 'as' => $today.".".$request->name.".".$request->role.'-Cover Letter.pdf', 'mime' => 'application/pdf'] );` something like this, it must work

Comment: I did as you suggested @BohdanPetrenko but it only sent one attachment in the email.